# Issue creating XML doc from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-xml

My intention is to iterate through my lovely dictionary (both key and value are strings) and create an xml file from it.

I get the error on the last line (saving the xml).

> "InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Token EndDocument in state Document would result in an invalid XML document."

Looking through this using breakpoints it would seem that at reaching the end of this, only the initial bit (outside the for each loop) has been done..

I'm half asking what silly mistake I've made, I'm partly asking if there's a more eloquent way of doing this.

Sorry if I've missed anything, let me know if i have, will add.

```
XDocument xData = new XDocument(
                   new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in inputDictionary)
{ 
        xData.Element(valuesName).Add(
            new XElement(valuesName, 
            new XAttribute("key", kvp.Key),
            new XAttribute("value", kvp.Value)));
}

xData.Save("C:\\xData.xml");
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your code, like what is xDoc and valuesName?

Comment: Indeed - you've got `xData` which you're ignoring, but not `xDoc`. Currently your `xData` document *just* has an XML declaration... it doesn't even have a root element. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Right sorry guys thanks for pointing that out. I've edited that now. When I was trying to figure out what I'd done wrong I tried another xDocument, but now this is all invovling xData (just a typo). Edited the above.

Comment: @Jonny: This is why it's useful to provide a short but *complete* example, which others can copy, paste, compile and run (unless you're reporting a compilation error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're adding multiple elements *directly* to the document - so you'd end up with either *no* root elements (if the dictionary is empty) or potentially *multiple* root elements (if there's more than one entry in the dictionary). You want a root element, and then your dictionary elements under that. Additionally, you're trying to *find* an element called `valuesName` without ever adding anything, so you'll actually get a `NullReferenceException` if there are any dictionary entries.

Fortunately, it's even easier than you've made it, because you can just use LINQ to transform your dictionary into a sequence of elements and put that in the doc.

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("root",
        inputDictionary.Select(kvp => new XElement(valuesName,
                                           new XAttribute("key", kvp.Key),
                                           new XAttribute("value", kvp.Value)))));
doc.Save(@"c:\data.xml");
```

Complete sample app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        XName valuesName = "entry";
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "A", "B" },
            { "Foo", "Bar" }
        };
        var doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("root",
                dictionary.Select(kvp => new XElement(valuesName,
                                               new XAttribute("key", kvp.Key),
                                               new XAttribute("value", kvp.Value)))));
        doc.Save("test.xml");
    }
}
```

Output (order of entries is not guaranteed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <entry key="A" value="B" />
  <entry key="Foo" value="Bar" />
</root>
```

An alternative breakdown for this would be:

```
var elements = inputDictionary.Select(kvp => new XElement(valuesName,
                                       new XAttribute("key", kvp.Key),
                                       new XAttribute("value", kvp.Value)));
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("root", elements));
```

You may find this simpler to read.

Comment: Perfect mate, thanks very much. I basically cut what I had done and followed your direction and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
XDocument xData = new XDocument(
                   new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

               XElement myXml = new XElement("paramList");// make sure your root and your descendents do not shre same name
               foreach (var entry in MyList)
                {
                       myXml.Add(new XElement(valuesName,
                                new XElement("key", entry.key),
                                new XElement("value", entry.Value)
               ));

xData.Add(myXml);
```